# Android Activity Group Implementation

Tags: android

i have multiple activities in my activityGroup under tabactvity.

1. I want to start the child actvity for result.

   Intent i = new Intent(this, addstocks.class);

   View view = stocksgroup.group.getLocalActivityManager()
     .startActivity("show_city", i
      .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
      .getDecorView();

   // Again, replace the view
      stocksgroup.group.replaceView(view);

this code basically taking me to the next activity. here i want to implement the actvity for result. hw can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

It ts very late but just for reference a demo can be seen here: [onActivityResult is not been invoked after the child activity calls finish()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344051/onactivityresult-is-not-been-invoked-after-the-child-activity-calls-finish)