# onActivityResult is not been invoked after the child activity calls finish()

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

Though there are several questions regarding this topic, I could not find a right answer to this.

I have a main activity (This is one activity in a tabview) from where I am calling the login activity.

```
    Button chdbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Add);
    chdbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(main.this, Login.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1001);
    }
    }); 


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode == 1001)
        {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                          Log.i("Info","Inside");
            }
        }
}
```

And in my login class, When I click on a button, I am doing this

```
    Button chdbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Addchild); 
    chdbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent Ireturn = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK,Ireturn);
                finish();
        }
    });
```

But when I click on the button in login activity, the control is not coming to the main activities onActivityResult method. Can anyone guide me what is the issue.

---

VIJAYapp.sample.ChildEntry1$1/onClick:23

INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=app.sample/.ChildLogin }

WARN/ActivityManager(59): startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=app.sample/.ChildLogin }

DEBUG/PhoneWindow(999): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43e4b620 has no id.

INFO/ActivityManager(59): Displayed activity app.sample/.ChildLogin: 460 ms (total 460 ms)

INFO/VIJAY(999): VIJAYapp.sample.ChildLogin$1/onClick:24

---

Above is the log that I am getting when clicking on the buttons. I can see that there is some problem with the Activity..any answers?

Comment: If you debug and put a breakpoint at the line "if(requestCode == 1001)" does that get hit? I suspect your onActivityResult is getting called, it just isn't getting to your Log message.

Comment: check the value of RESULT_OK whether it is same in both the class

Comment: I have already tried putting a breakpoint at the starting of the onActivityResult function, but it never got hit. I have put log statements at the beginning of all the function to print the file, function and line number and this is what I get

Comment: 06-14 20:24:33.689: ERROR/VIJAY(586): VIJAYapp.sample.ChildEntry1$1/onClick:46
06-14 20:24:50.370: ERROR/VIJAY(586): VIJAYapp.sample.ChildLogin$2/onClick:49

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is solved now. I made some modifications to your code and the onActivityResult is now called (check the modified code: http://www.4shared.com/file/_VR3zi28/CopySampleApptar.html?):

1.-When you call the Login activity class use: getParent().startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1001);

I am not very skilled in Android but I understand that the one controlling the flow among activities is the ActivityGroup class, so you should start the activities using the ActivityGroup instance. In the previous line getParent() makes reference to the ActivityGroup.

2.-Because you use the ActivityGroup instance, your onActivityResult must be placed in that class as well.

Comment: u r not silver_mx u r a gold_mx Thanks bro.. :) and +1

Comment: That link is not available is it possible to post that code once more I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing the lines

```
        Intent Ireturn = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK,Ireturn);
```

with

```
setResult(RESULT_OK,getIntent());
```

getIntent() returns the Activity that started Login.

Comment: @vijay Consider posting the error after updating the code and also consider putting a call to Log.d in onActivityResult